# Which tables are safe to omit from sql-sync?

Tags: theming, drush

I sync my database with `drush sql-sync @dev @live` and the other way round. Can I omit the following tables safely, like in my `drushrc.php` from `sql-sync`?

```
$options['structure-tables'] = array(
   'common' => array(
     'cache', 'cache_filter', 'cache_menu', 'cache_page', 
     'cache_admin_menu' 'cache_block', 'cache_coder', 
     'cache_content', 'cache_form', 'cache_hierarchical_select', 
     'cache_location', 'cache_update', 
     'cache_views', 'cache_views_data', 
     'ctools_css_cache', 'ctools_object_cache', 
     'history', 'sessions', 'watchdog'
   ),
);
```

Additionally I wanted to exclude **variable_cache** and **views_object_cache** if that is safe.

Is that a good practice? Is there a list of tables somewhere on drupal.org for all modules?

Answer (score 2):

If you update to the latest dev version of Drush, you will find the following definition in examples/example.drushrc.php:

```
# $options['structure-tables']['common'] = array('cache', 'cache_*', 'history', 'search_*', 'sessions', 'watchdog');
```

The wildcard syntax is very useful, as with it, it is no longer necessary to make a comprehensive list of all cache tables used by all of your contrib modules.  Note that you must use the latest version of Drush pulled from git; the 8.x-6.x-dev from 18 June does not have wildcard support.