# How to exclude the user table using the drush sql-sync command

Tags: drush, database

How do I exclude Drupal's user table from drush's `sql-sync` command?

Comment: If you don't syncronize the users table you will have problems with entity references like nodes, orders etc...

Comment: Related: [which tables are safe to omit from sql-sync](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/77480/16495)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command is executed like this, if you're going to ignore the users table might as well ignore roles and permissions too, but that's up to you:

```
drush sql-sync -v --skip-tables-list=users,users_roles,role_permission @prod @dev
```

`-v` is optional and will display what the command is doing & confirm the tables are being skipped like so:

```
The following tables will be skipped: role_permission,users,users_roles
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use `--skip-tables-list` flag on your `drush sql-sync` command

```
drush sql-sync @prod @dev --skip-tables-list=user
```

the table lists should be comma seperated.

For more options on `sql-sync` check [this documentation](http://www.drushcommands.com/drush-5x/sql/sql-sync).